# DataTables add data in row dynamically after validate button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In my project I'm trying to add label (ex: `OK` or `NOK`) in the row at column **Validate** using [DataTables](https://datatables.net) but i can't manage it.

When i click on **Open** a new modal appear and then when i click on the content button **HVV** i would like to add a label in the column **Validate** (see pictures). How i can do that please ?

JSFiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/9ecb3sxr/

[image]
[image]

Comment: Add what label? `HVV`?

Comment: From where you are adding label??

Comment: Like in my OP post : `add label (ex: OK or NOK)` then with boot strap i will add class like success or danger. It's just a flag to a status after clicking the HVV button. I hope I'm enough clear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove `data: null` for last column, add `defaultContent: ''`.
2. Pass row Id to modal as data property `data-row-id="' + rowIdx + '"`.
3. Upon closing the modal, update the required column:

   ```
   var rowIdx = $(event.target).data('row-id');
   $("#dispo").DataTable()
       .cell({ row: rowIdx, column: 3})
       .data('<div class="label label-success">Valid</div>')
       .draw(false);
   ```

I don't understand the logic with `OK`/`NOK` states but you should get an idea and adjust the code accordingly.

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ecb3sxr/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: the updated fiddle link is having the same issue I guess.

Comment: Looks cool now. I owed you because you had helped me long back with an issue :) you rock Brother!!

Comment: @Gyrocode.com : your code works good **but** the problem is with `tableResp` ! For the jsFiddle i put the the html code directly to the script because i can't use AJAX POST in jsFiddle. This html is the response from my request so i can't add `data-row-id="' + rowIdx + '"` to it :\
There is another way to do it please ? BTW thank you for this great piece of code !!

Comment: @Peacefull, attach data directly to modal window then, see https://jsfiddle.net/9ecb3sxr/2/

Comment: @Gyrocode.com : it's wonderful ! thank you very much for helping me ! this last update jsFiddle works for me :) have a good day bro